# Valgind: non-zero exit code only if memory is definitely lost

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, exit-code

We use `valgrind` as a part of our CI process. If there are some memory problems, `valgrind` must return non-zero code, and this incident is reported. This is how we run it:

```sh
valgrind --error-exitcode=1 --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full \
    --errors-for-leak-kinds=definite --show-leak-kinds=definite \
    --track-origins=yes ./some_cgo_application

(...)

==25182== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25182==     in use at exit: 2,416,970 bytes in 34,296 blocks
==25182==   total heap usage: 83,979 allocs, 49,684 frees, 5,168,335 bytes allocated
==25182== 
==25182== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25182==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25182==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25182==      possibly lost: 3,024 bytes in 7 blocks
==25182==    still reachable: 2,413,946 bytes in 34,289 blocks
==25182==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==25182==                         newarray           : 520 bytes in 1 blocks
==25182==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25182== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==25182== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==25182== 
==25182== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25182== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Currently we're interested only in memory that is `definitly lost`. If no blocks are definitly lost, `valgrind`'s exit code is expected to be zero. However, it returns `1` despite of the options `--errors-for-leak-kinds=definite --show-leak-kinds=definite`.

```sh
echo $?
1
```

Are thery any other options that will help to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the exit status 1 comes from the program itself.  I can reproduce this with:

```
$ valgrind --error-exitcode=1 --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full \
  --errors-for-leak-kinds=definite --show-leak-kinds=definite \
  --track-origins=yes /bin/false
```

This does not look like something that can be changed in the current sources:

```
   case VgSrc_ExitProcess: /* the normal way out (Darwin) */
      /* Change the application return code to user's return code,
         if an error was found */
      if (VG_(clo_error_exitcode) > 0 
          && VG_(get_n_errs_found)() > 0) {
         VG_(client_exit)( VG_(clo_error_exitcode) );
      } else {
         /* otherwise, return the client's exit code, in the normal
            way. */
         VG_(client_exit)( VG_(threads)[tid].os_state.exitcode );
      }
```

And this `exitcode` member is set from the `sys_exit_group` wrapper in `coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-linux.c`, without any way to tweak it.

Considering this, I think your best bet (without patching valgrind) is to select an exit status different from any exit status your program might use, and use that as an indicator of a valgrind error.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the --gen-suppressions option. With this you can create a file that tells valgrind to suppress call-stack-specific possibly lost and still reachable errors. Using this file, re run valgrind with --supressions=filename. Now the return value of valgrind ($?) will be zero. Here's an example:

```
valgrind --gen-suppressions=auto --log-file=suppressions.supp ./path/to/program
<open suppressions.supp, delete all lines that are not suppressions, save, and close>
valgrind --suppressions=suppressions.supp ./path/to/program
echo $?
```

You should see zero printed.

This won't future proof your code for new possibly lost and still reachable errors, but it will remove current errors. If you want to future proof your code you could write a script that parses the output of --gen-suppressions=auto and generates a new suppressions file. The script can be made so that it only adds suppressions for possibly lost and still reachable errors, so you would still see the errors you care about.